# Javascript canvas drawImage results in blank? -revised-

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage, lit-element

I'm working inside a lit-element component trying to draw an img element onto a canvas element:

```html
return html` 
  <img></img>
  <br>
  <canvas width="1500" height="1500"></canvas>
  <br>
  <input type='file' accept='image/*' @change=${this.readImage}> </input>
`
```

```js
  readImage(event) {
    // Get the image element
    var img = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img')
    // Get the file
    var file = event.target.files[0]
    // File reader
    var reader = new FileReader()
    // Handle read
    reader.onload = event=>{
       img.src = event.target.result
       // Get the canvas element
       var canvas = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('canvas')
       // Get the canvas context
       var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
       // Draw image on canvas
       context.drawImage(img,0,0)
    }
    // Read the file
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

However for some reason the canvas element remains blank. I can't seam to find out where I'm going wrong or if I'm running into some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use onload to make sure the image has finished loading.  Is there a reason you aren't just using a `new Image()` object instead of using an embedded img element?

```js
this.shadowRoot=document;

function
readImage(event) {
  // Get the image element
  var img = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img')
  // Get the file
  var file = event.target.files[0]
  // File reader
  var reader = new FileReader()
  // Handle read
  reader.onload = event => {
    img.onload = () => {
      // Get the canvas element
      var canvas = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('canvas')
      // Get the canvas context
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      // Draw image on canvas
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    }

    img.src = event.target.result
  }
  // Read the file
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

```html
<img></img>
<br>
<canvas width="1500" height="1500"></canvas>
<br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange=readImage(event)> </input>
```

Comment: Thnx! This wasn't obvious to me.